# How do I loop through different iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I am stuck on how to load one iframe and have the next one queuing to be displayed. How would I write a script that loops through different iframes after time?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i=0;i<self.frames.length;i++) {
    var buttons = self.frames[i].document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    // Do stuff with buttons
}
```

Hope it will do your work

Comment: What is `self`? It is not described neither in the question nor in the answer.