# Unable to getElementById on one specific site

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

Working on creating an auto-login app, but I'm running into a problem on the following site:
https://www.navient.com/loan-customers/

**Site Element**

```
<input type="text" id="lblUserId" value .../>
```

[image: Username Text ID]

**Console Code**

```
document.getElementById('lblUserId').value = 'testUserName';
```

**Error Message**

[image: Error Message]

Any ideas why this isn't working? I've tried it on several other sites and it works perfectly.
Thanks ya'll!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the site uses frames. switch above console "top frame" to "ctl16_frlogin"

Comment: Awesome! Any idea how I would account for that factor code-wise?

Comment: Just found this, gonna give it a shot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040901/how-do-i-loop-through-different-iframes

Comment: Just decided to set the login page to whatever the frame's source is. Thanks for your quick response, cari.